# Populating dropdownlist client side. Getting post back validation error

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a webcontrol with two dropdownlists on in. When you choose something from the first, the second is populated accordingly. When post back occurs I get the old:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a
>   page.  For security purposes, this
>   feature verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate
>   from the server control that
>   originally rendered them.  If the data
>   is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

I know what this problem is; I am populating the dropdown with unexpected data. I've read up on the error and found fixes like overriding the Render method where you call "RegisterForEventValidation" for each new dropdownlist item. I can't do this, however, as I am repopulating the dropdown client side.

In theory I could use this method if I added every possible value (around 3000) that could be included in the dropdown, but I didn't really want to do this.

Are there any other ways of getting around this error, without disabling EventValidation or populating the dropdownlist server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to use a basic html select and look for the selected value on the `Request.Form` collection.

With the `DropdownList` I'm afraid you have no other option but those 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used the Select and it was exactly what I needed. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no support for disabling event validation on a per-control basis. In my experience, though, disabling event validation on a page is not all that bad.

Regardless of whether event validation is enabled, wise developers validate all input. Tools like [the AntiXSS library](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) can come in handy for identifying and/or sanitizing potentially malicious input.

If you are already following practices where you carefully validate form input, then disabling the out-of-the-box ASP.NET validation behavior should be a viable solution that doesn't add substantial risk to your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will look into that library. The reason I can't disable event validation is that this webcontrol can be used from the majority of the sites pages and I wouldn't like to disable validation for the whole site. Would be ideal if I could disable it just on the webcontrol itself, but I'm pretty sure I can't

Comment: @Gareth - Good luck. I have also been disappointed that validation cannot be disabled on a per-control basis. You may find @Claudio's recommendation to use a generic HTML select to be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Render method may solve your issue. But, faster is subclassing. Do nothing, but subclass your DropDownList and use that in your aspx page.

I did it, and worked.