# Dropdown Filtering ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am looking to find the best way to do the following:

1. Filter data based on the drop down filters, as long as I am within the same product category (e.g. toys, puzzles, etc...), but in different web forms (product grid and product detail).  So if I select toys under $25, I need the filter to the toys in a grid format, but if I click to view the detail I need the filter information so I can filter the related items display.
2. Display certain filters depending on the product category.

Right now I believe that if I build a user control and session variables that I should be able to accomplish this.  Do anyone know of any examples of doing something like this or have a better way?  Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:  Right now I am using the page_load event to update the data and would like to avoid AJAX for right now.

Wade

Comment: Sounds like you are on the right track. You should be able to combine all of the functionality in one or more user controls and either use viewstate or session to store information as needed.

Comment: You can use the enable client post backs on drop down list:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659724/populating-dropdownlist-client-side-getting-post-back-validation-error

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use something similar to cascading drop downs with Ajax.

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: I am looking to avoid AJAX for the moment due to the fact I would need to rewrite the product grid code.  Thanks though.

Comment: You would enable client post-back on each drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

The Ajax toolkit has an example of how to do this in C# and in VB.net:
http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Comment: I am looking to avoid AJAX for the moment due to the fact I would need to rewrite the product grid code.  Thanks though.